# text parsing issue - how to parse correctly

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing

I have the following text which i am trying to 'tidy' by putting all categories onto their own line. Im not sure how to do it using regex or any other method.

> Name:branding-SLES Relocations: (not relocatable)
>
> Version:11 Vendor: SUSE LINUX Products GmbH, Nuernberg, Germany
>
> Release:3.20.30 Build Date: Fri Feb 3  2012
>
> Install Date: Wed Sep 24  2014 Build Host: gubaidulina
>
> Group:System/Fhs Source RPM: branding-SLES-11-3.20.30.src.rpm
>
> Size:1659 License: BSD 3-Clause
>
> Signature:RSA/8, Fri Feb 3  2012, Key ID e3a5c360307e3d54
>
> Packager:http://bugs.opensuse.org
>
> Summary:SUSE Linux Enterprise Server Brand File

should be

> Name:branding-SLES
>
> Relocations: (not relocatable)
>
> Version:11 Vendor: SUSE LINUX
>
> Products GmbH, Nuernberg, Germany
>
> Release:3.20.30
>
> Build Date: Fri Feb 3  2012   Install Date: Wed Sep 24  2014
>
> Build Host: gubaidulina   Group:System/Fhs
>
> Source RPM: branding-SLES-11-3.20.30.src.rpm
>
> Size:1659 License: BSD 3-Clause
>
> Signature:RSA/8, Fri Feb 3  2012, Key ID e3a5c360307e3d54
>   Packager:http://bugs.opensuse.org
>
> Summary:SUSE Linux Enterprise Server Brand File

I dont mind doing some edits on it before hand (removing certain spaces etc) to help the overall aim.

Comment: This can be done with a list of keywords that are more than two words, otherwise it uses a single word. I'll post what I mean.

Comment: thx, look fw to it :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a list of keywords that are more than two words,
otherwise it uses a single word.

The reason to use known words is there is nothing regex-wise to determine the
start of phrases.

Replacement is `\n$1`

**edit** - update to regex (consume/strip preceding whitespace)

```
 #  @"\s*\b((?:\w+|Keywords1|Keywords2|Keywords3):)"

 \s*                     # Strip all preceding whitespace(will get replaced with \n)
 \b 
 (                       # (1 start)
      (?:
           \w+           # default, single word
        |  Key words1    # or, known words or phrases
        |  Key words2
        |  Key words3 
      )
      :
 )                       # (1 end)
```

Comment: Hey thx man, ive went back to drawing board with th eidea its not possible to format without knowing the keywords. What does the 'n$1 do?

Comment: @Fearghal - Its the replacement, causes a newline to be inserted before keyword.